# WPF - Как отследить перерисовку ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Есть коллекция объектов, у каждого их которых есть свойство ParentId.
Есть ListBox, к которому привязана эта коллекция объектов. В ListBox.ItemContainerStyle определен Setter, меняющий свойство Visibility в зависимости от совпадения ParentId элемента ListBox, и viewModel.ParentId. Т.е. каждый раз при изменении viewModel.ParentId происходит перерисовка ListBox.

Вопрос: как отследить **окончание** перерисовки ListBox? LayoutUpdated не предлагать, он дёргается от малейшего шевеления мышкой.

Comment: зачем вам это делать? Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: На самом деле, коллекция объектов состоит из контролов типа DataGrid. Соответственно, при изменении видимости элементов ListBox меняется всё дерево визуальных объектов внутри него. Мне нужно запустить некий процесс после окончания перерисовки VisualTree. Сейчас приходится вызывать ListBox.Items.Refresh() и ListBox.UpdateLayout(), это работает, но здорово подтормаживает.

Comment: `коллекция объектов состоит из контролов типа DataGrid`  в WPF... вы не тем путем пошли...

Comment: Можно попробовать написать панель или наследника ContentControl и вызывать событие в ArrangeOverride после Arrange контента, а ваш ListBox сделать его контентом

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это не я пошел, это legacy-код. Как руки дойдут, я это поменяю, но сейчас нужно работать с тем что есть